# "Getting shot out" for an object?

Tags: expressions, idiomatic-language

I vaguely heard somebody describing broken objects as getting shot out. I briefly looked up dictionaries, and the only "close enough" definition was (well) from Urban Dictionary. I already suspected it was slang, so I think it's not a huge problem.

But the definition there wasn't satisfactory because, according to that, "getting shot out" was meant for broken persons, not broken objects. My mother tongue happens to have a conceptually equivalent expression ("맛이 가다" or "the taste has gone bad" if translated literally), and it's mainly used to describe people. However, using it to describe broken objects is perfectly fine and idiomatic.

I wonder if that's the case for "getting shot out." Is it idiomatic to call an object "got shot out" if it is broken? Or is there any other casual idiomatic way to say broken?

Comment: I’ve never heard it. What I have heard is calling something **shot**.  “I was cutting the grass when I ran over a rock. Now the mower is **shot**.”   Or “I spent all afternoon splitting firewood, and now I’m **shot**.”

Comment: The Urban Dictionary is not a reliable resource.  It's hard to answer a question on something you "vaguely heard".  I am not aware of "shot out" being in any way synonymous with something being broken.  It's more likely describing how it got broken - by being shot out of a machine, or something like that.  It's not an idiom. It's literal.

Comment: There is an idiom saying that something is "shot to pieces" - which means thoroughly broken into pieces.  I wonder if that is what you heard?  Also, shot can mean ruined as in "shot to hell" or as my late father used to say when confronted with something that is no longer working "it's all shot to buggery".

Comment: Another similar expression (from the UK) which can be used to describe people or objects is to say that someone/something is knackered. (not functioning/tired/broken/ruined),   This comes from the word "knacker", originally a person who slaughters old/sick horses.

Comment: @BillyKerr, similarly to Brit *knackered*, in the US we use the word *beat* as an adjective meaning very tired. I presume it’s based on the (hyperbolic) metaphor of having been physically beaten and being as a result tired out and sore.

Comment: Without sufficient context, or an assurance that you heard it correctly, I don't see how this question can be answered.